# Can youtube-dl perform multiple downloads to different directories?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

[Youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) runs with python

I would like to download multiple YouTube playlists (using the archive feature), but I want those to be downloaded to different local directories.

I can get this to work for one playlist going to one directory:

```
 youtube-dl --download-archive "F:\Videos\Online Videos\Comics
 Explained\Marvel Major Storylines (Constantly Updated)\Marvel Major
 Storylines Archive.txt"
 "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9sO35KZL50yZh5dXW-7l93VZp7Ct4vYA"
 -o "F:\Videos\Online Videos\Comics Explained\%(playlist_title)s\%(title)s.%(ext)s" -f
 "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best"
 --ffmpeg-location "H:\Documents\FFMpeg\bin"
```

but I don't know if I can do this for multiple playlists going to a separate directory for each playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invocation already does create multiple directories, one for each playlist, simply by using template sequences such as `%(playlist_title)s` in your `-o` parameter. The only thing that's missing is multiple playlists. Fortunately, you can just append the playlist URLs to your command line, like this:

```
youtube-dl \
  --download-archive "F:\Videos\Online Videos\Comics Explained\Marvel Major Storylines (Constantly Updated)\Marvel Major Storylines Archive.txt"
  -o "F:/Videos/Online Videos/Comics Explained/%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s" \
  -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" \
  --ffmpeg-location "H:\Documents\FFMpeg\bin" \
  \
  PL9sO35KZL50yZh5dXW-7l93VZp7Ct4vYA \
  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=YOUR_PLAYLIST_HERE \
  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=YOUR_SECOND_PLAYLIST_HERE \
  ...
```

(The backslashes at the end of lines are not needed if you write the whole command in one line)

Comment: I didn't know I could put the playlists at the end; nice post :)

What if I wanted to save MP3 extractions into a separate, sub-directory?

i.e. F:/Videos.../MP3/[file name]

Comment: @Stack Johan That sounds like a separate question, unrelated to playlists and `--download-archive`. Feel free to [ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `--exec` which would create a new directory and then move the downloaded item into the new directory: `--exec 'mkdir {} && mv {} /{}'`